# Compare two controls with eachother

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I'm working my way through CodedUI and thus far I'm impressed by how it works and what can be achieved with it. However I want to compare two values (In two seperate WPF screens) with eachother and I can't get it to work. When I record my workflow with the Coded UI Test Builder I can Assert a property of a Control using the 'Dart'-drag and drop item but I can't change the Comparison Value to the Content value of another Control...

Does anybody know how such thing is achieved?

Answer (score -1):

Make assert for both controls to some value. Generate your test. You will have two assert methods, take a look into these methods how your controls will be accessed in assertion. Replace the constant(wrapper) through the control's value in one assert method, delete the other assert method. So you have what you have wanted - a test, which compares two control's contents.